# Convergence of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the following series converge or diverge?
$$ 1 - \frac{3}{4}+ \frac{4}{6} - \frac{5}{8} + \frac{6}{10} - \frac{7}{12} + \cdots $$

Comment: Doesn't look like the terms converge to zero, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see the series as being $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{2n}$ and $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0$ so it doesn't converge.